# jquery .autocomplete only displays last record in set

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am processing nested `getJSON` data in the below code, where > 1 record is returned and sorted by autocomplete.

```html
{
  "ok": [
    {
      "myName": "Back Office",
      "myModule": "back01",
      "myDesc": "Developing a the platform"
    },
    ......
    ]
}
```

When the final data (lets say 6 matching records) are passed to `.autocomplete( "instance" )` each call to update `return $( "<li>" )` seems to overwrite the previous returned JSON data, meaning only the last record is displayed instead of the 6 that are valid Is the JSON.

I note that when debugging the .autocomplete routine is looping through the correct number of times to match the number of records, it is just that each loop seems to overwrite the `<li>` with a fresh object rather than append to the previous record.

Why is the overwrite happening?

thanks
Art!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#my_module_in" ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: function( request ,response){
                    $.getJSON("https://api.myapi.com/getStuff", function (data) {

                        $.each(data, function (okKey, val00) {
                            if ( okKey === 'ok') {
                                $.each(val00, function (key201, val201) {
                                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                        return {
                                            label: val201.myName,
                                            value: val201.myModule+"_"+val201.myDesc,
                                        }
                                    }))
                                })
                            }else{
                                console.log("error:noJson");
                            }
                        })

                    });
                },

                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    console.log(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#my_module_in" ).val( ui.item.label);
                    $( "#my_module" ).val( ui.item.value);
                    $( "#my_module_description" ).html( ui.item.value );
                    return false;
                }
            })

                    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li>" )
                        .append( "<div>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.value + "</div>" )
                        .appendTo( ul );

            };

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="my_module_label">Op_Group</div>
<input id="my_module_in">
<input type="hidden" id="my_module">
<p id="my_module_description"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an empty array containing the results found in the `$.each ($.map())` operation. Then, in the `$.map()` function, for every item push the current object in the empty array.

Finally, call the response callback function with the array that you filled.

```
var result = [];
$.each(val00, function(key201, val201) {
  $.map(data, function(item) {
    result.push({
      label: val201.myName,
      value: val201.myModule + "_" + val201.myDesc
    });
  });
});
response(result);
```

Something like this:

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $("#my_module_in").autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/51e9ea30dddd09d9f82a8e78b8a51de2/raw/9ad8b1b40377a6807548b444491846dd13025902/getStuff.json", function(data) {

          $.each(data, function(okKey, val00) {
            if (okKey === 'ok') {
              var result = [];
              $.each(val00, function(key201, val201) {
                $.map(data, function(item) {
                  result.push({
                    label: val201.myName,
                    value: val201.myModule + "_" + val201.myDesc
                  });
                });
              });
              response(result);
            } else {
              console.log("error:noJson");
            }
          });
        });
      },

      focus: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item.label);
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#my_module_in").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#my_module").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#my_module_description").html(ui.item.value);
        return false;
      }
    })

    .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      return $("<li>").append("<div>" + item.label + "<br />" + item.value + "</div>").appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="my_module_label">Op_Group</div>
<input id="my_module_in" type="text">
<input type="hidden" id="my_module">
<p id="my_module_description"></p>
```